# Magnetic quantum numbers - axes correspondence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, coordinate-systems, orbitals

We know that the [magnetic quantum number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_quantum_number) describes the space orientation of an orbital within an atom. For the $p$-orbital, the magnetic quantum numbers can be -1,0,1 (one for every axis). We have three axes $x$, $y$, $z$ and three quantum numbers (for the $p$-orbital) -1,0,1. How are these two groups related to each other? Does -1 correspond with the $x$-axis, 0 with the $y$-axis and 1 with the $z$-axis?

What about more complicated orbitals having more possible space orientations? How are the axes and magnetic quantum numbers related?

Comment: No, it doesn't go that -1 is for x axis, 0 for the y axis and +1 for z. For atoms in which the Coulomb field doesn't have spherical symmetry, there may exist an axis of symmetry, let's take it as axis $z$. But only for $m = 0$ one has rotational symmetry around this axis. For $m \neq 0$ when rotating around this axis there appear nodes (regions where the wave-function intensity is very low). But you can see all these things in Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Angular_momentum.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic quantum numbers $m$ give you the projection of the angular momentum $L$ in units of $\hbar$ on *one* specified axis, normally the $z$- axis. So it's not *one* $m$ for *every* axis, but *multiple* $m$'s for *one* axis.

For the $P$-state for example - that is $L=1$ - the projection on the $z$-axis can take on the values $$\hbar,0,-\hbar~,$$

so $m=+1,0,-1$.

Here is a picture for visualization (the one in the middle corresponds to the $P$-state):

[image]

Now, one could ask the question why a spherically symmetric atom should have a preferred axis. (Just like the $z$-axis.)

As I understand it, the choice of the $z$-axis as a preferred axis is merely a convention. This choice results from the fact that the components of the $L$- operator ($L_x,L_y,L_z$) don't commute with each other, but each of the components commutes with $L^2$. This means, that you can measure $L^2$ and one component of $L$ simultaneously, and by convention this is the $z$-component.

To clarify this a bit: say you have a box filled with hydrogen atoms, each of those atoms randomly oriented in space and each in the same $L\neq 0$- state. Since you're a wizard you made a special device where you can measure the square of the angular momentum ($L^2$) and *one component* of the angular momentum simultaneously. When you activate the device, you know these numbers for each atom, e.g. $$L^2=6\hbar^2$$ and $$L_?=2\hbar~. $$

Now you know the $L$-component $L_?$ for each atom. Which one is it? It doesn't matter if it's the x-,y- or z-component because in the calculations you choose to have simultaneous eigenfunctions for $L^2$ and one of the components at some point. But since all the other wizards use the $z$-component, you also choose the $z$-component $L_z$.

Comment: As I understand it, the choice of the $z$-axis as a preferred axis is merely a convention. This choice results from the fact that the $L_i$- operators don't commute with each other, but each of the $L_i$'s commutes with $L^2$. This means, that you can measure $L^2$ and *one* component of $L$ simultaneously, and by convention this is the *z*-component.

Comment: Sure! But if you like you can leave the comment, it's a valid objection.

Comment: Your answer now is good and complete. Have a point from me too.

Answer (score 0):

The $p$ orbitals that you refer to are actually certain linear combinations of the ones we usually use with the magnetic quantum number, i.e., the wave=functions are of the form
$$\begin{eqnarray}p_z &=& p_0\\
p_x &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(p_1 + p_{-1} \right)\\
p_y &=& \frac{1}{i\sqrt{2}} \left( p_1 - p_{-1} \right)\\\end{eqnarray}$$
where the subscripts correspond to $m$. The picture is not so nice for higher values of $\ell$, but it depends on the symmetries of the spherical harmonic functions $Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\varphi)$, which form representations of the rotation group $SO(3)$. We can always pick a different set of axes, and find a different set of spherical harmonic functions as linear combinations of the old ones.

I would like to try to answer your second question. In general, an atom is in a superposition (linear combination) of these orbital states, so one doesn't normally picture an atom with it's orbitals pointing in a certain direction, even though they are often drawn that way. However, we can try to measure the angular momentum by placing the atom in a magnetic field. Then the different orbitals correspond to different energies, and we can put the atom in a particular state depending on the orientation of the magnetic field (e.g. in a Stern-Gerlach type experiment).